# Hide Text Widget visibility in Flutter on the click of button

Tags: flutter

I want to hide a text widget visibility on the click of a button using                 Visibility widget. How can I achieve this in Flutter? I have created a function which accepts a bool variable which defines the visibility of the Text Widget. On the click of the button, I am calling that function. For the first time, the text is shown to the user. But on the click of the button, the text is not invisible.

```
//created a method to show and hide the text using visibility widget
hideTextVisibility(bool visibilityStatus){
return visibilityStatus? Visibility(
visible: visibilityStatus,
child: Text("flutter"),

):Container();}



//button click code and for the first time the text will be visible 
RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
setState(() {
hideTextVisibility(false);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing hardcode **false** to the button's method `hideTextVisibility(false);` just change here `hideTextVisibility(visibilityStatus);`

Answer (score 18):

Step 1:

```
bool _visible = false;
```

Step 2:

```
void _toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _visible = !_visible;
    });
  }
```

Step 3: 
 Add on your RaisedButton or any other button

```
onPressed: _toggle,
```

Step 4:
Code your widget like this.

**Gone: The widget doesn't take any physical space and is completely gone.**

```
Visibility(
  child: Text("Gone"),
  visible: _visible,
),
```

**Invisible: The widget takes physical space on the screen but not visible to user.**

```
Visibility(
  child: Text("Invisible"),
  maintainSize: true, 
  maintainAnimation: true,
  maintainState: true,
  visible: _visible, 
),
```